# Flutter: _ClientSocketException Failed host lookup

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

i try to retrieve the data from restapi , it worked before, after weeks, it doestn work anymore . try to call api using generated dart code from postman. the link i put on flutter and postman is same link but only postman work. i have header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' header but i dont know where to put so i put in authorizationHeader instead

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   List? users;
  bool loading = false;

  Future<String> getUsers() async {
    setState(() => loading = true);
    var response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://linkishere.com/all'),
            headers: {
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'thekeyishere',
    }, );

    // setState(() => users = json.decode(response.body.toString()));
    Map<String, dynamic> users = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

    setState(() => users);

    setState(() => loading = false);
    
    return 'success';
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUsers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('REST API'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          loading
              ? const Center(
                  heightFactor: 12.0,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                      itemCount: users == null ? 0 : users!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        var name = users![index]['rows']['drainageid'];
                        var email = users![index]['email'];
                        var website  = users![index]['rows']['region'];

                        return Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              leading: const CircleAvatar(
                                child: Icon(Icons.account_box),
                              ),
                              title: Text(name),
                              
                              subtitle: Text(website),
                            ),
                            const Divider(),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

even i have internet on my physical devices and put android permission on xml file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

how do i call api from flutter and get the same result as postman